# How to host 2 projects on 2 different subdomains using virtual hosts in MAMP

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm not quite sure what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Currently I'm using MAMP to host my projects myself. These projects are hosted and can be accessed by people who know my IP address when they type my IP address in their URL bar. When they access my IP, my they see a list of my project directories like this:

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that when someone types `charter.54.135.14.176` he sees the content of the charter folder and when he types `LeagueOfLegendsFrontend.54.135.14.176` he is presented the content of League Of Legends Frontend folder.

I've been looking at tutorial videos about virtual hosts and I was left confused. I understand I have to do 2 things:

First, go to httpd-vhosts.conf and create a virtual host for each project. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ???
    ServerAlias ???
    DocumentRoot "C:\MAMP\htdocs\Charter"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ???
    ServerAlias ???
    DocumentRoot "C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Frontend"
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm kind of clueless what am I meant to write on ServerName and ServerAlias

And secondly, I need to go to the hosts file and add this:

```
54.135.14.176   ???
```

And lastly I need to include virtual hosts by uncommenting `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in httpd.conf file. Sadly I'm stuck on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate two different IP addresses for your projects. So, the desired configuration may look like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName charter.zxc
    DocumentRoot "C:\MAMP\htdocs\Charter"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:80>
    ServerName lol-frontend.zxc
    DocumentRoot "C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Frontend"
</VirtualHost>
```

You, of course can add directory settings, logs and other things if necessary, but I only show the very basic setup. Then in your hosts file add:

```
127.0.0.2 charter.zxc
127.0.0.3 lol-frontend.zxc
```

Comment: No matter which IP I visit, I always get presented with the root folder htdocs instead of the actual specific project.

Comment: @Bobimaru First of all, I suggest you ttrying the same thing on XAMPP, because MAMP is really bad designed. If that doesn't work, show me the full content of your httpd-vhosts.conf, etc\hosts and .htaccess files of your projects. Which version of Windows do you use?